# Successful login redirects to login page

Tags: php, authentication

I am being redirected to login page after successful login. Please find below codes for vhost set up in wamp and post method loginaction.php.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/aklc_portal/admin"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/aklc_portal/admin">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

POST method loginaction.php

Tried with these three individually:

```
$refererURL =$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
$refererURL ="/index.php";
$refererURL ="http://localhost/aklc_portal/admin/index.php";

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
  {
     //check DB
     //set cookie
  }

 else {
     //other logic. New reffererURL
}

//redirect

header("Location: ".$refererURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove or comment

```
$refererURL =$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]

$refererURL ="http://localhost/aklc_portal/admin/index.php";
```

because your root directory is `aklc_portal / admin /` you just have to point to the index and the third `$refererURL` is overwriting the first and second